# How to call parametrized method in ngOnInit in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6

How to call parametrized method in ngOnInit in the same component.
I have an onclick(p.key) function in html, which is defined in ts file, but I want to populate it in ngOnInit. Is it possible

Files are as:
1. product-filter.component.html

```
<div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        [class.active]="!price" routerLink="/">
          All Price
        </a>
        <a *ngFor="let p of price$ | async" 
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        routerLink="/" (click)="onClick(p.key)"
        [class.active]="price === p.key">     
              {{p.name}}
        </a>
</div>
```

2. product-filter.component.ts

```
onClick(p) 
{
    if(p == '20 - 30') {
       this.productService.getAll().subscribe(products => {
        this.products = products.filter(product => {
        return product.price >= 20 && product.price <= 30
      });      
    });
}
```

Now I want to call this method in ngOnInit(). Is it possible?. Any suggestions is most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing stops you from calling it from ngOnInit like the following:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.onClick("The initial Id you want to start with");
}
```

Comment: Even I did the same way but it says could not find 'p' in this.onClick(p)

Comment: You won't pass p as a parameter, you're going to pass the content of p, hardly coded to your function.

I think that you didn't post the question properly, don't you just want to call the method initially in ngOnInit with a custom value you're choosing?

Comment: Actually I've not paassed the parameterized method before in ngOnInit... I want the products range defined in method onClick to be called in ngOnInit... this is where I'am confused

Comment: I think you're confused on what you want. You can't get the product range when using onclick, simply because there is no click. You can only get the product range, when there is a click event on one of the elements of the ngFor list of elements.

If you want one particular product to be used intially, all you need to do is pass its id to the function. I mean, this.onClick(this.prices[index]), index being the index of element you want to use inside the onClick initially.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can place the function within ngOnInit() and invoke it. In that case you need to pass the initial parameter as hard coded value.

Comment: can you give example please

Comment: what do youmean /